# Save cell changes when pressing on another cell

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a kendo ui grid which has an incell editing mode.
Required is when altering a value in a cell and pressing anywhere else a confirmation window to appear to save/cancel the change.

Right now i have managed to make it partially work. In other words when i change a value and press somewhere on the web page or a button i get the confirmation window as requested. 
When i press on another cell nothing happens. The pressed cell gets in edit mode, the "edit" function is fired but the previous cell loses its value and the binded function is never called.

So in a few words, i need to call my confirmation function every time a value is changed and the user presses anywhere else. Right now it partially works. It seems that the function is not fired when pressing on another cell.

My source right now is like that.

```
edit: function(e) {
    e.model.unbind("change", confirmationFun).bind("change", confirmationFun);  
}

function confirmationFun(e){ 
    // open confirmation dialog and call save function  
}
```

I tried to combine my confirmation with the change: function(e)  but the change is fired every time i press on a cell, even before i change a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was finally resolved by removing the **selectable: "multiple cell"**
part from my code. Now by pressing on a different cell i get the confirmation dialog as required.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `edit` event, you might use `blur`. After the initialization of your `grid` add the following command that binds any [`blur`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp) to your `confirmationFun` function.

```
$('#grid').on("blur", "input", confirmationFun);
```

Where `grid` is the `id` of your KendoUI `grid`.

Comment: I saw some posts that fire blur event everytime a cell looses focus, but I need to fire it only when a particular collumn cell loose focus. here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20853104/how-to-catch-kendo-grid-cell-out-of-focus-event. Can you plz help?