# how to catch kendo grid cell out of focus event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

In my kendo grid, I want to put some value in a cell & then after leaving the cell, based on the value of that cell, I need to put some other value on the adjascent cell. How can I do that?

I have studied the following jsfiddle, the problem is its triggering the event everytime I'm getting out of any cell, but I need to fire the event for only one column's cell.

http://jsfiddle.net/latenightcoder/6ZNqN/1/

here is my grid:

```
//To Define Columns for Yearly Holiday Kendo Grid
        var YearlyHolidayGrid = $("#YearlyHolidayGrid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: YearlyHolidayDataSource,
            pageable: true,
            editable: true,
            edit: function (e) {
                var input = e.container.find(".k-input");
                var value = input.val();
                input.keyup(function () {
                    value = input.val();
                });
                input.blur(function () {
                    //$("#log").html(input.attr('name') + " blurred : " + value);
                    //var a = new Date();
                    //a = value;
                    //var day = a.getDay();
                    //alert(day);
                    alert(value);
                });
            },
            selectable: "row",
            navigatable: true,
            filterable: true,
            sortable: true,
            height: 200,
            columns: [
                  { field: "HLDY_SLNO", title: "SL", width: "50px" },
                  { field: "HLDY_DATE", title: "Date", width: "100px" },
                  { field: "HLDY_DAY", title: "Day", width: "100px" },
                  { field: "HLDY_NAME", title: "Holiday Name", width: "100px" },
                  { field: "HLDY_TYPE", title: "Holiday Type", width: "100px" },
                  { field: "HLDY_STATUS", title: "Holiday Status", width: "100px", editor: YearlyHolidayStatus },
                  { field: "HLDY_DFIN_TYPE", title: "Defined as", width: "100px", editor: YearlyHolidayDefinedAs },
                  { field: "HLDY_REM", title: "Remarks", width: "100px" },
                  { command: [{ name: "DeltedRow", text: "Delete"}], title: "Delete", width: 100 }
            ]
            //change: function () {
            //    var row = this.select();
            //    var id = row.data("id");

            //  //  $("#log")
            //  //      .html("selected row with id= " + id + " \
            //  //, for ShipName = " + dataSource.get(id).get("ShipName"));
            //}
        });
```

Plz help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should change the `selector` when you define the `blur` event handler to choose only the column that you want.

In the JSFiddle that you say that you have studied, it is originally defined as:

```
edit: function(e) {
    var input = e.container.find(".k-input");
    var value = input.val();
    input.keyup(function(){
        value = input.val();
    });
    input.blur(function(){
        $("#log").html(input.attr('name') + " blurred : " + value);
    });
},
```

You should define it as:

```
edit: function(e) {
    var input = e.container.find(".k-input");
    var value = input.val();
    input.keyup(function(){
        value = input.val();
    });
    $("[name='ShipName']", e.container).blur(function(){
        var input = $(this);
        $("#log").html(input.attr('name') + " blurred : " + value);
    });
},
```

Where I use as selector `[name='ShipName']` i.e. set `blur` only for an HTML `input` with the attribute `name` equals `ShipName`.

If you play now with the modified version ([here](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/6ZNqN/114/)) you will see that only displays in the log the value when the column is `ShipName`.

**EDIT:** If you need to get all the items in your model so you can change another column, you might use `dataItem`. The steps are:

```
// Find the row being edited:
var row = $(this).closest("tr");

// Get the item using `dataItem`:
var item = grid.dataItem(row);
```

The modified Fiddle to display the ShipCity when ShipName is blurred here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/6ZNqN/116/

Comment: ok, I got the value, now I need to set some value to the next column's cell which is named as "HLDY_DAY". I'm trying but may be it will take you just a min. so plz help a little more when you get time. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Check **EDIT** for details on getting the model.

Comment: This worked great for me I just had to use ".k-textbox" rather than input, maybe due to newer lib or a grid config difference.  Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

```
function onCellEdit(e) {
    try {
        $('.text-box.single-line').change(function () {
            hasUnSavedChange = true;
        });
    }
    catch (err) {
        error_handler(err);
    }
}
```